# Can't logout in my django project, it doesn't redirect correctly

Tags: django, django-views

I'm implementing a log in/ log out script in my django project but the log out is not working.

This is my code `index.html`,

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <!--<title> {% block title%}{% endblock%} </title>-->

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>

            <h2> Hola {{ user.username }} </h2>
            <a href="/logout/">Log out</a>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I just declare a link `<a href="/logout/">Log out</a>` that has to redirect the user to the log out view. **I think maybe the error is here that I'm not redirecting correctly to the view**.

My `views.py`. Here I just want to confirm the log out and redirect to the login page.

```
 def logout(request):
    auth.logout(request)
    messages.info(request, 'Log out done!')
    return redirect('login')
```

My `urls.py` from the app of `Usser_App`,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
]
```

My `urls.py` from the "general" app,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Platform_App/', include('Platform_App.urls')),
    path('Users_App/', include('Users_App.urls')),
]
```

I know the last one is working because the login is working. The problem is when I click in log out link, that is not redirecting correctly.

I tried,

```
<a href="/logout/">Log out</a>
```

[image]

And

```
<a href="Users_App/logout/">Log out</a>
```

[image]

But not work.

How I have to do it? I'm sure is easy, but I can't see where is the problem.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Have you tried redirecting like this `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('logout'))` ?

Comment: No, what is the difference doing one or other?

Comment: the reverse() function looks through all the URLs defined in urls.py and find the one which matches with the name defined in urls.py. HttpResponeRedirect() renders that URL into Http and redirects to it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. You think the problem is on the redirect from the view and not on the link?